# Are conditional typedef's possible in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, type-traits

this question is related to c++

there is a library which declares a class named Solver < TS,FS >. Solver is a member of another class Domain (written by me)

now there are many Domains which have a member "int region"

what i want to do is depending on the value of region, I want to make the solver accept different arguments for TS and FS. 
I was thinking of something along the line

```
template<int region>
struct Decider
{
  if(region==1)
  {
     typedef TSA TS;
     typedef FSA FS;
  }
  else
  if(region==2)
  {
     typedef TSB TS;
     typedef FSB FS;
  }
}
```

and later use it as

```
Decider<region>::TS
Decider<region>::FS
```

However, here due to the scope of the if, i guess the struct is useless. However, I am not able to think of a better method to do this. Any suggestions?

All the different TS and FS have the same interface. So I don't have to worry about the inside code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can specialize a template for any `region` value.

```
template<int region>
struct Decider;

template<>
struct Decider<1>
{
     typedef TSA TS;
     typedef FSA FS;
};

template<>
struct Decider<2>
{
     typedef TSB TS;
     typedef FSB FS;
};
```

Comment: It should be noted that the template argument must be a compile-time constant. Since the OP said that he wanted to use a member variable `int region` as argument, I am afraid this solution will not fulfill its needs...(I may have misunderstood the question, of course.)

Comment: yes.... it would be preferable to have it as int region
but i guess i can manage with a compile time constant tooo.
will just make the code longer i suppose.......

Comment: just to make sure i can do like this right?
`using Decider<region>::TS; Solver<TS> solver();`

Comment: @Jayesh Badwaik, No, but you can write `typedef Decider<region>::TS TS; Solver<TS> solver;` where's `region` is a compile time constant. The `using` keyword is for using namespaces.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use template specialisation.

```
template <int region>
struct Decider;

template <>
struct Decider<1>
{
    typedef TSA TS;
    typedef FSA FS;
};

template <>
struct Decider<2>
{
    typedef TSB TS;
    typedef FSB FS;
};
```

C++ will choose which version to use based on the `region` supplied.

You can, of course, extend this as you see fit for other region numbers.

Comment: suppose I want one definition for region=1 and an another definition for region!= 1 then, is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

If you need to parameterize `Decider` based on some compile time constant, you can use template specialization (see other answers).

If you need to parameterize `Decider` based on a runtime value of `region`, you have to defer the parameterization to runtime as well. Usually this is done through some sort of creation function or factory idiom.

Answer (score 2):

Note for anyone coming across this now:

It is also possible to do this with the boost libraries using the [type_trait boost::conditional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/conditional.html).

```
typedef boost::conditional<condition, type_if_true, type_if_false> MyTypeDef;
```

`condition` still needs to be a compile time expression that evaluates to true or false. This also makes it so you don't need to specialize your entire class for just a few lines of differences.

Comment: It is really freaking awesome!! :-)